# How to remove string with number within a column in SSIS derived column?

Tags: ssis

(SSIS topic) I have a column named street name that contains strings with number. I want to remove those PO Boxes in the street name column.

```
|street name         |address        |
|Queen Street        |6 Queen Street |
|Main Street         |11 Main Street |
|PO Box 5678         |PO Box 5678    |
|PO Box 1234         |PO Box 1234    |
|PO Box 9876         |PO Box 9876    |
```

This is the outcome that i want to achieve.

```
|street name         |address        |
|Queen Street        |6 Queen Street |
|Main Street         |11 Main Street |
|                    |PO Box 5678    |
|                    |PO Box 1234    |
|                    |PO Box 9876    |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expressions would be challenging to use for this task.  I would suggest using a script component:

1) Add a script component transformation

2) Check the column with the street name (which I called address) and mark it as readwrite

[image]

3) Add the following to the script:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
using System.Linq; //be sure to add Linq to the namespaces

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        if (Row.address.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray().Length > 0)
        {
            Row.address = "";
        }
    }

}
```